# Why patched method of the class behaves differently from the patched method of the patched class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest.mock

I am playing with patches and mocks and trying to understand the difference
between patch of the method of a class and patch of the method of patched class.
In both cases I create class instance and try to patch the bound method by bounded one with
the explicit directive `autospec=True`. However, in first case I successfully
patch the method with expected behaviour whereas in second case the
patched object behaves unexpected.

It demonstrates the following code:

```
from mock import patch

class B(object):
    def zero(self):
        return 0

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = B()
        self.i = self.y.zero()

def mocked_zero(*args, **kwargs):
    return 1

a = A()
assert a.i == 0  # expected

with patch('__main__.B.zero', autospec=True) as mocked_B_zero:
    mocked_B_zero.side_effect = mocked_zero
    a = A()
    assert a.i == 1  # expected
    mocked_B_zero.assert_called_once_with(a.y)  # expected

with patch('__main__.B', autospec=True) as mocked_B:
    instance = mocked_B.return_value
    instance.zero.side_effect = mocked_zero

    # I placed the following line but it changes nothing
    instance.zero.autospec = True

    a = A()
    assert a.i == 1  # expected
    instance.zero.assert_called_once_with()  # why does it pass?
```

I expected the directive `autospec=True` will do the work and `instance.zero.assert_called_once_with(a.y)`
will pass instead.

It should be noticed that directive `autospec=True` changes the `mocked_b` object.

```
with patch('__main__.B') as mocked_B:
```

creates an object `mocked_B`: `<MagicMock name='B' id='...'>`. Whereas

```
with patch('__main__.B', autospec=True) as mocked_B:
```

creates a different object `mocked_B`: `<MagicMock name='B' spec='B' id='...'>`

The is a great explanation of meaning of the keyword argument `autospec=True` in case of patching class method:

[Mock's autospec injects a wrong argument into a called function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878750/mocks-autospec-injects-a-wrong-argument-into-a-called-function/27892226#27892226)

https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python  (see comments)

but it remains unclear the meaning of the directive `autospec=True` in case of
class patching.

So, I have several questions:

1. What does directive `autospec=True` means in case of entire class patching?
2. Why `instance.zero.assert_called_once_with()` passes in case of
   method patching of the patched class?
3. Is it possible to patch a bound method by a bounded one in the second case so that `instance.zero.assert_called_once_with(a.y)` passes?

**UPDATE**

The situation where the need to patch both class and one of its method appears.

I need to test a class, say `A`, that uses in its implementation another class, say `B`. Simplified it looks like this:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        pass

    def get_items(self):  # instead of 'zero' function
        while True:  # infinite loop
            item = self.request_to_db(some_params)
            yield item

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, config)
        self.b = B(config)

    def run(self):
         for item in self.b.get_items():
            do_some_action(item)
```

I need

1. to check that instantiating the class `A` like `a = A(config)` the class `B` was called with parameter `config`.
2. to check that calling `a.run()` the method get_items was called and is placed into the loop.

For this purpose I want

1. to patch the entire class `B` with some mock object
2. to patch the method `get_items` with some specially constructed  mock object (side_effect option is used here)
   raising `StopIteration` exception after defined number of iterations.

Of course, `do_some_action` method is also patched.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to test in the second scenario?

Comment: I have extended my question explaining the situation where the need to patch both class and method appears. Hope, it is more clear now. Actually, I guess, I know how to reach the goal. But I don't understand why patching solely class method and patching the entire class and then patching class method yields the objects with different behaviour despite usage `autospec=True` option.